# Reshaping when year and countries are both columns

Tags: stata

I am trying to `reshape` some data. The issue is that usually data is either long or wide but this seems to be set up in a way that I cannot figure out how to `reshape`. The data looks as follows:

```
year   australia   canada  denmark ...
1999   10          15      20
2000   12          16      25 
2001   14          18      40
```

And I would like to get it into a panel format like the following

```
year    country    gdppc
1999    australia  10
2000    australia  12
2001    australia  14
1999    canada     16
2000    canada     18
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is just in the variable names. See e.g. [this FAQ](http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/data-management/problems-with-reshape/) for the advice that you may need `rename` first before you can `reshape`.

For more complicated variants of this problem with similar data, see e.g. [this paper](http://www.stata-journal.com/sjpdf.html?articlenum=dm0031).

```
clear 
input year   australia   canada  denmark 
1999   10          15      20
2000   12          16      25 
2001   14          18      40
end 
rename (australia-denmark) gdppc= 
reshape long gdppc , i(year) string j(country) 
sort country year 
list, sepby(country) 

     +--------------------------+
     | year     country   gdppc |
     |--------------------------|
  1. | 1999   australia      10 |
  2. | 2000   australia      12 |
  3. | 2001   australia      14 |
     |--------------------------|
  4. | 1999      canada      15 |
  5. | 2000      canada      16 |
  6. | 2001      canada      18 |
     |--------------------------|
  7. | 1999     denmark      20 |
  8. | 2000     denmark      25 |
  9. | 2001     denmark      40 |
     +--------------------------+
```